# How to assign a javascript variable to google customer review data

Tags: javascript, variables, google-tag-manager

Hello and thanks for your help in advance!

I'm currently trying to implement Google Customer Reviews into our webshop, however I do this using Google Tag Manager.

My question is: How can I use the variable "dateReview" as value for "estimated_delivery_date"?

```
var datePurchased = new Date();
var dateReview = (datePurchased.getFullYear() + '-' + (datePurchased.getMonth()+1) + '-' + (datePurchased.getDate()+3);

  window.renderOptIn = function() {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
      window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
        {
          "merchant_id": 0000000,
          "order_id": "10",
          "email": "test@test.com",
          "delivery_country": "NL",
          "estimated_delivery_date": dateReview,
        });
    });
}
```